# Microsoft Natural Ergonomic 4000 volume hotkeys delay

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

When I press the volume up or down hotkeys on my Microsoft Natural Ergonomic 4000 keyboard(s), there is a delay - sometimes of up to 30 seconds, before windows reacts to it. At other times they work instantly.

I think the delay happens if I have not used the keys since last reboot - or maybe after the computer comes out of sleep.

I have observed this same behaviour on 3 different PCs and 3 different physical keyboards (all same model). They have all run Windows 7 64bit, and I have not installed any special software, other than what Windows itself decides to install with the driver (Intellitype).

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I know exactly what you're talking about. But even though I rebooted and restarted `itype.exe` multiple times, I can no longer reproduce it. I tried capturing what happens with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), but now it works every time :(

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: After moving to Win8, I no longer have the problem...

Comment: I'm having a sort of delay problem but with my spacebar, no idea why since the rest works OK

Comment: I know this is a 3 year old post but I am experiencing the same annoying delay - did you ever find a solution.

Comment: @JonHolland I upgraded to Windows 8 and then the problem was gone. :-S

Comment: cheers, don't have the option at work - wonder what windows 10 might bring.

Comment: I had this problem with the "My Favorites" keys being extremely slow to respond in Window 10.  After the 1607 Windows 10 update, the delay seems to be gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a horrendous interaction with a virus scanner.

Here's how I reproduced:

1. Reboot computer
2. Enable Microsoft Security Essentials
3. Press Volume-Down key once

   - ==> Wait **52 seconds** for a response.
4. Reboot computer
5. Disable Microsoft Security Essentials
6. Press Volume-Down key once

   - ==> Normal response (Kinda-instant. <1s anyway.)

*Specs: Win7-64, Core2 i7-860 (4-cores), SSD system drive.*

**UPDATE:**

- No clues from running Resource Monitor: no high CPU, disk or network activity was apparent.
- Excluding the `Microsoft IntelliType Pro` folder from scanning did not help. :-(

Answer (score -1):

Download the most recent driver from Microsoft.

http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/downloads